# Returning IEnumerable Implementation from within Task

Tags: c#, casting, task, ienumerable

I can do:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Do()
{
   return new List<string>();
}
```

But if I'm returning a Task, I'm not allowed to do the same thing:

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<string>> DoTask()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return new List<string>(); //no no
    });
}
```

I'm implementing a async repository in .NET 4.0 and ran across this. I was just curious why the compiler can't cast my `List` down when wrapped in a Task? Of course, my work around is just throwing `AsEnumerable` on it , but I wonder why this limitation exists?

Comment: Should be duplicate of "why there is no cast from `Type<T>` to `Type<IT>` for  T:IT"... hopefully someone will find exact link or simply repost an answer.

Comment: Sure, I couldn't phrase the question correctly enough to locate a duplicate.  I'd be happy to close it if it's answered.

Comment: Not sure, but Actions (the lambda) return no type, right? Wich error do you get?

Comment: @MVCDS type of `()=> return new X()` is `Func<X>` in this context, not `Action` as lambda is returning value (added similar info to answer also).

Answer (score 4):

Converting from `Task<List<string>>` to `Task<IEnumerable<string>>` require [`Task<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx) to be covariant AND inner types to be interfaces. Neither is true in this case, so conversion not allowed.

Obvious fix - to cast result of `Task` to necessary type either by explicitly specifying type for lambda

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew((Func<IEnumerable<string>>)
  (() =>
  {
    return new List<string>(); 
  }));
```

or implicitly by casting result:

```
  return (IEnumerable<string>)new List<string>();
```

Detailed information - [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

---

Why `Task<List<string>>` is result of TaskFactory.StartNew call:

Lambda passed to the `StartNew` call does not explicitly specify its type so compiler infers its return type from `return` statement. Since `return` clearly states `new List...` overall type of lambda is equivalent in this case to `Func<List<string>>`.

Comment: Note: Should be duplicate, but I can't find good duplicate answer yet.